# Invoking Java program from PL/SQL function and handling Java exception

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I have a PL/SQL function that wraps a Java stored procedure. I want to handle the returned exception by inserting the exception to a table.

```sql
create or replace 
FUNCTION req(request VARCHAR2, ip VARCHAR2, port NUMBER)
RETURN VARCHAR2 AS LANGUAGE JAVA
NAME 'MRPosting.MRPost(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, int) return java.lang.String';
```

How can I get the returned exceptions and then insert it to a table?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create another procedure (using plain PL/SQL) that calls the Java function.  This procedure needs to contain an exception handler that does the insert.  Or you could have the Java function do the insert, it depends on your situation.